# Mysql TimeStampDiff Min Time Minus Max Time - Grouping Error

Tags: mysql, max, min

Goal:  Calculate total time an agent spends in each campaign by day.
Issue: Using Min and Max end with "incorrect" results.
Current Query:

```
SELECT agent,campaign,DATE(eventfield) AS created,TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,MIN(TIMESTAMP(eventfield)),MAX(TIMESTAMP(eventfield))) / 3600 AS Hours
FROM log1
WHERE eventfield > '2015-01-19'
AND eventfield < '2015-01-20'
GROUP BY agent,campaign,created
```

SAMPLE DATA:

```
agent    campaign    eventfield
alfalfa  apples      2015-01-19 09:00:00
alfalfa  apples      2015-01-19 09:11:00
alfalfa  pears       2015-01-19 09:11:00
alfalfa  pears       2015-01-19 16:30:00
alfalfa  apples      2015-01-19 16:30:00
alfalfa  apples      2015-01-19 17:00:00
```

**Expected Results:**

```
agent    campaign    created      hours
alfalfa  apples      2015-01-19   0.6833
alfalfa  pears       2015-01-19   7.3167
```

***Actual Results:***

```
agent    campaign    created      hours
alfalfa  apples      2015-01-19   8.0000
alfalfa  pears       2015-01-19   7.3167
```

Comment: why is created in group by?

Comment: you're using date strings to compare datetime values. since you haven't provided time values on your date strings, PHP is extending them to `00:00:00` for the time, throwing off the comparisons. `foo < '2015-01-20'` is going to execute as `foo <= '2015-01-19 23:59:59'`

Comment: @TonyHopkinson - corrected the select statement, forgot to add after removing sensitive info for example.

Comment: @MarcB - Corrected my selected of eventime, it is a DATETIME field.